# there is no subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ containing only 3 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that there is no subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ containing only 3 elements.

I couldn't solve why 3 elements cannot exist.

0 and 2 are the only subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ with 2 elements. But 3 elements??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Lagrange's theorem is available, then Evan W's answer is exactly what you want, but if you don't (yet) have Lagrange's theorem, then you can do this small example by hand; after all, $\mathbb Z/4$ has only four subsets of 3 elements each. Whichever of the four elements of $\mathbb Z/4$ you omit in order to form a 3-element subset, the omitted element will be the sum of two of the others (0=2+2; 1=2+3; 2=1+1; and 3=1+2), so your 3-element subset won't be a subgroup.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean a *subgroup* of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ containing 3 elements.

Lagrange's Theorem: "The order of a subgroup $H$ of group $G$ divides the order of $G$."

3 does not divide 4, so there cannot be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ containing 3 elements.